# Only Users with Owner Role can send invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, rolify, devise-invitable

Am working with Rolify,Devise,CanCanCan and devise_invitable, the setup has been perfect,i have two roles "owner" and "member", and i have 3 models, User,Project and Gig, User has_many Project and Project has_many Gig vice versa, my question is,how do i ensure only users with role "owner" can send invitation to a new user.

Ability.rb

```
  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
       user ||= User.new 

      if user.has_role? :owner
        can :invite, User
        can :manage, Project, user_id: user.id
      elsif user.has_role? :member
        can :manage, Gig, user_id: user.id
      else
        can :manage, Project
      end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles


belongs_to :resource,
           :polymorphic => true,
           :optional => true


validates :resource_type,
          :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
          :allow_nil => true

scopify
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  resourcify
  rolify 

  has_many :projects,dependent: :destroy
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

invitations_controller

```
 class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
    before_action :is_owner?, only: [:new, :create]

    private 
    def is_owner?
        current_user.has_role? :owner
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others who may encounter such problem, here is how i got it work, modify the invitations_controller like this.

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
   def new
     if cannot?( :invite, User )
       raise CanCan::AccessDenied
     else
       build_resource
       resource.practice_id = current_practice_id
       render_with_scope :new
     end
   end
   def create
     if cannot?( :invite, User )
       raise CanCan::AccessDenied
     else
       super
     end
   end
end
```